# Height of a TreeSet in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, red-black-tree

Is that possible to compute the exact height of the Red-Black tree used in the TreeSet class in Java? I don't care about time complexity at all.

Moreover, is it possible to know how many children (0 or 2) a node has in the TreeSet object.

Note that we don't have access to anything but a reference to an object of TreeSet.

Comment: If you're doing this for the purpose of debugging, optimization, tests, etc., you can do this with reflection.

Comment: No, I don't want to go that far :)

Comment: It is not possible without reflection, because the TreeSet object doesn't expose that kind of information through its public API.

Comment: If you're just curious, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) explains nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given only a reference, there is nothing you can do without reflection. With reflection on a `TreeSet` instance T, you will want to:

1. access its backing `NavigableMap`, which by default will be a `TreeMap`. Let us call it M.
2. access M's root, of type `TreeMap.Entry`
3. use a simple recursive algorithm to get depth (max depth = height) and any other information on the nodes.

This may seem daunting, but it is actually much easier than it appears:

```
public class TreeSpy {

    private static Object get(Object o, String fieldName) {
        try {
            Field declaredField = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            declaredField.setAccessible(true);
            return declaredField.get(o);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not gain access to field "
                    + fieldName + " of " + o.getClass());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static int diveInto(Object n, int depth, String indent) {
        if (n == null) return depth-1; // we are empty, and should not be counted
        Object left = get(n, "left");
        Object right = get(n, "right");
        String key = (String)get(n, "key");

        int childrenCount = 0 + (left!=null?1:0) + (right!=null?1:0);
        System.out.println(indent + key +
                ": depth=" + depth + ", chidren=" + childrenCount);
        return Math.max(
                diveInto(left,  depth+1, indent+"  "),
                diveInto(right, depth+1, indent+"  "));
    }

    public static void showDepthAndChildren(TreeSet<String> set) {
        TreeMap<String, Object> m = (TreeMap<String, Object>)get(set, "m");
        Object root = get(m, "root");
        int maxDepth = diveInto(root, 1, "");
        System.out.println("Height = Max Depth = " + maxDepth);
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        TreeSet<String> test = new TreeSet<>();
        for (String s : "once upon a time in a galaxy far far away".split(" ")) {
            test.add(s);
        }
        showDepthAndChildren(test);
    }
}
```

Note that we cannot mention the type of nodes explicitly, because the class `TreeMap.Entry` has private access. However, we can still use objects of the type to inspect properties.

The output on my machine (JDK8) is:

```
once: depth=1, chidren=2
  galaxy: depth=2, chidren=2
    away: depth=3, chidren=2
      a: depth=4, chidren=0
      far: depth=4, chidren=0
    in: depth=3, chidren=0
  upon: depth=2, chidren=1
    time: depth=3, chidren=0
Height = Max Depth = 5
```